# Horizontal navigation bar not working in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am creating a navigation menu with HTML and CSS. But it is not working properly in Firefox 19. I tried to fix it for hours. But no luck.

My problem is when hover on submenu display a border around menu item. It is working properly on google chrome and safari. But not in firefox and IE 7 and 8.

This is my CSS :

```
#nav a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #c5c5c5; 
}

#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0441B, #BB3415);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#D0441B, #BB3415); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#D0441B', endColorstr='#BB3415'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#D0441B', endColorstr='#BB3415')"; /* IE8+ */  
    border-color: #B5501A;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #C97B4B inset;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}


#nav li:hover ul li.current-sub  {
    background: #ffdfbd;
}   

#nav li:hover ul li.current-sub  a {
    color: #5f3100;
}       

#nav li:hover ul li.current-sub:hover {
    background: #ffcd98;
    border: none !important;
}   


/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    border: none !important;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #ffefdd;

}

#nav ul li a:hover {        
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;  
    border-radius: 0;   
    border: none;
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;     
    z-index: 999;
}
```

This is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCnQq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make more use of the child selector `>`. I applied it to this statement:

```
#nav .current > a, #nav > li:hover > a {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D0441B, #BB3415);
    /* ... */
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCnQq/1/).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get fiddle to run in IE8, even if it is completely empty. So I can't test.

Comment: Linus Caldwell another problem I found. That is when sub menu's menu item activate again display a border around the items. now hover is ok. this is my styles for submenu's active link - `#nav li:hover ul li.current-sub  {
  background: #ffdfbd;
 } 
 
 #nav li:hover ul li.current-sub  a {
  color: #5f3100;
 }  
 
 #nav li:hover ul li.current-sub:hover {
  background: #ffcd98;
 }`

Comment: I tried it like this - `#nav li:hover > ul li.current-sub  {
  background: #ffdfbd;
 } 
 
 #nav li:hover > ul li.current-sub > a {
  color: #5f3100;
 }  
 
 #nav li:hover > ul li.current-sub:hover {
  background: #ffcd98;
 }` but not working...